# How to enable hardware acceleration in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, hardware-acceleration

I want to enable hardware acceleration in fragment how to integrate it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't enable hardware acceleration only at a fragment level.

[As per documentation:](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel#controlling)

> You can control hardware acceleration at the following levels:
>
> - Application
> - Activity
> - Window
> - View

Comment: I'm using youtube player fragment & it requires HW acceleration. And my app requires HW acceleration false. My youtube videos get blackout when HW acceleration is false.

Comment: @MukulKanojia You can just disable it for the app, and enable it for the activity that holds this fragment

Comment: @MukulKanojia Another tip that you can give a try; you can build this fragment in another `Window`, as per the answer, you can control the hardware acceleration at window level, so you might think of `DialogFragment` for instance

Comment: yeah the same I'm trying to do. I will let you know if that works. Thanks!!

Comment: How did you solve it? How to enable hw acceleration in DialogFragment?

Comment: @TalhaÇ unfortunately you can't.. The system doesn't allow that on the fragment level

Comment: @Zain i solved my problem by View level. I enabled hw acceleration for the Activity and disabled for the needing View.